# fetching max value from a python dict of dict

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary of dictionary as 
`z = {'a' : {'p' : 5, 'q' : 7}, 'b' : {'p' : 9, 'm' : 8}, 'c' : {'p' : 7},'d' : {'n' : 9, 'm' : 9}}`

I have to fetch the maximum value from dict of dict and assign it to the key.

The output should be:
`z = {'a' : {'q' : 7}, 'b' : {'p' : 9}, 'd' : {'n' : 9, 'm' : 9}}`

I am new to Python. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far (forming a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example), example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: So you want to find the maximum value for each *nested* dictionary, and replace that dictionary with one containing just the key-value pair for that maximum value? I note that you seem to have included both `'n'` and `'m'` for the dictionary under `'d'`; so you want to find **all** keys for a given maximum value then? Please make such requirements *explicit* rather than have us infer them. Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Answer (score 0):

The following session with the interpreter should show you one way to accomplish what you are after:

```
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> z = {'a': {'p': 5, 'q': 7}, 'b': {'p': 9, 'm': 8}, 'c': {'p': 7}, 'd': {'n': 9, 'm': 9}}
>>> z = {key_a: {key_b: value_b for key_b, value_b in value_a.items() if value_b == max(value_a.values())} for key_a, value_a in z.items()}
>>> z
{'a': {'q': 7}, 'b': {'p': 9}, 'c': {'p': 7}, 'd': {'n': 9, 'm': 9}}
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks Noctis. But here is 1 problem as value of inner dict whose key is 'p' is already there in the outer dict's key as 'b'. Then also in key as 'c', its displaying the value of inner dict 'p' as 7.

I just want the max value among all for particular key in the inner dict.

Thanks a lot for helping me out

Comment: Could you clarify your question up above; specifically, why is key 'c' missing in the outer dictionary?

Comment: Because Outer key 'c' has a inner key 'p' whose max value is already saved in outer key 'b's inner key.. I just want to store a unique key in inner key across outer keys. Like 'p' should occur once in the inner key in the dict of dict with the maximum value.. I hope I am clear now. thanks